# external JavaScript components not showing up on mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I used the following Library (gme.js) in my application.

http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/index.html

When I run the app on the worklight console, I am able to see the textbox and map as you can see from screen #1 and it works perfectly fine. But when I run the app on my mobile device, the textbox and map are not showing up.

The following is the html code:

```
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
              <title>sampleApplication</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
            maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 

        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.3.min.css">
        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>
        <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
            src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
             src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js">
           </script>
          <script src="js/medicare-static-ds.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/gme.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/store-locator.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/storelocator.css">

            <style type="text/css">
             body { font-family: sans-serif; }
             #map-canvas, #panel { height: 500px; }
                #panel { width: 300px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
               p.attribution, p.attribution a { color: #666; }
                </style>
              </head>

      <body >
        <div data-role="page">

         <div data-role="content" >

            <div id="panel" class="storelocator-panel" style="width : 100% ; height : 30%;" >   
            <form class="storelocator-filter">
            <div class="location-search">
            </div>
            <div class="feature-filter">
            </div>
            </form>

                   </div>
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have added the following permissions in AndroidManifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.DemoPoC.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

The following is LogCat file.

```
    09-11 17:11:03.867: D/CordovaActivity(30165):
    onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
    09-11 17:11:03.957: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(30165): Unable to open asset URL:
    file:///android_asset/www/default/js/skinLoader.js
    09-11 17:11:04.057: D/CordovaWebViewClient(30165):
    onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
    09-11 17:11:04.057: D/CordovaActivity(30165):
    onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
    09-11 17:11:04.337: D/CordovaActivity(30165): onMessage(spinner,stop)
    09-11 17:11:04.347: I/chromium(30165): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)]
    Async pixel transfers not supported
    09-11 17:11:04.367: D/CordovaNetworkManager(30165): Connection Type: wifi
    09-11 17:11:04.437: I/chromium(30165): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)]        
    Async pixel transfers not supported
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdutils(30165): FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO failed
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.447: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.457: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.457: W/PluginManager(30165): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to 
    WLApp.writeUserPref blocked the main thread for 46ms. Plugin should use
    CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
    09-11 17:11:04.467: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.467: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.467: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:04.467: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:04.467: D/CordovaNetworkManager(30165): Connection Type: wifi
    09-11 17:11:04.467: D/CordovaActivity(30165): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
    09-11 17:11:04.477: D/CordovaActivity(30165):
    onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
    09-11 17:11:06.079: D/CordovaActivity(30165): onMessage(spinner,stop)
    09-11 17:11:06.750: D/CordovaActivity(30165): onMessage(spinner,stop)
    09-11 17:11:06.760: D/CordovaNetworkManager(30165): Connection Type: wifi
    09-11 17:11:06.780: D/CordovaLog(30165): file:///android_asset/www/default/js/medicare
    static-ds.js: Line 21 : Uncaught ReferenceError: storeLocator is not defined
    09-11 17:11:06.790: I/chromium(30165): [INFO:CONSOLE(21)] "Uncaught ReferenceError:
    storeLocator is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/medicare-static- 
    ds.js (21)
    09-11 17:11:06.790: D/CordovaLog(30165): file:///android_asset/www/default/js/gme.js: Line 3   
    : Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    09-11 17:11:06.790: I/chromium(30165): [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] 
   "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined", source:
   file:///android_asset/www/default/js/gme.js (3)
   09-11 17:11:06.810: D/CordovaLog(30165): file:///android_asset/www/
   default/js/store-locator.min.js: Line 110 : Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
   09-11 17:11:06.810: I/chromium(30165): [INFO:CONSOLE(110)] 
  "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined", source: 
   file:///android_asset/www/default/js/store-locator.min.js (110)
   09-11 17:11:06.850: E/NONE(30165): Uncaught Exception: Uncaught 
   ReferenceError: storeLocator is not defined at (compiled_code):21
  09-11 17:11:06.860: E/NONE(30165): Uncaught Exception: Uncaught
   ReferenceError: google is not defined at (compiled_code):110
  09-11 17:11:06.870: E/NONE(30165): Uncaught Exception: Uncaught 
  ReferenceError: google is not defined at (compiled_code):3
  09-11 17:11:07.401: D/CordovaWebViewClient(30165): 
  onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
  09-11 17:11:07.401: D/CordovaActivity(30165): 
  onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
09-11 17:11:07.411: D/NONE(30165): ondeviceready event dispatched
09-11 17:11:07.451: D/NONE(30165): wlclient init started
09-11 17:11:07.461: D/NONE(30165): Read cookies: null
09-11 17:11:07.471: D/NONE(30165): CookieMgr read cookies: {}
09-11 17:11:07.501: W/NONE(30165): Note that if your application targets
 Android 3.0 (API level 11) or higher, WL.OptionsMenu might have no effect, 
 depending on the device.
09-11 17:11:07.541: D/NONE(30165): before: initOptions.onSuccess
09-11 17:11:07.541: D/CordovaLog(30165): file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js: 
Line 1036 : processMessage
 failed: Message: S01 DeviceAuth123798908 s27958d34-bd47-33df-aca2-28b41f7469b7
     09-11 17:11:07.541: I/chromium(30165): [INFO:CONSOLE(1036)] "processMessage failed: Message:         
 S01 
DeviceAuth123798908 s27958d34-bd47-33df-aca2-28b41f7469b7", source:  
file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js (1036)
     09-11 17:11:07.551: D/CordovaLog(30165): 
 file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js:
 Line 1037 : processMessage failed: Error: ReferenceError: google is not defined
 09-11 17:11:07.551: I/chromium(30165): [INFO:CONSOLE(1037)] "processMessage failed: Error: 
   ReferenceError: 
  google is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js (1037)
  09-11 17:11:07.561: D/CordovaLog(30165): 
   file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js: 
  Line 1038 : processMessage failed: Stack: ReferenceError: google is not defined
  09-11 17:11:07.561: D/CordovaLog(30165):     at wlCommonInit 
 (file:///android_asset/www/default/js/main.js:45:8)
  09-11 17:11:07.561: D/CordovaLog(30165):     at wlEnvInit 
  (file:///android_asset/www/default/js/main.js:53:5)
  09-11 17:11:07.561: D/CordovaLog(30165):     at Object.wlInit [as onSuccess] 
  (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7394:5)
  09-11 17:11:07.561: D/CordovaLog(30165):     at finalizeInit 
  (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:6744:15)
      09-11 17:11:07.561: D/CordovaLog(30165):     at Object.<anonymous> 
      (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7564:7)
  09-11 17:11:07.561: D/CordovaLog(30165):     at Object.<anonymous> 
      (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1202:33)
  09-11 17:11:07.561: D/CordovaLog(30165):     at fire 
  (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1047:30)
      09-11 17:11:07.561: D/CordovaLog(30165):     at Object.self.fireWith [as resolveWith] 
  (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1158:7)
  09-11 17:11:07.561: D/CordovaLog(30165):     at Object.deferred.(anonymous function) [as 
   resolve] 
      (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1247:34)
    09-11 17:11:07.561: D/CordovaLog(30165):     at deviceIDSuccessCallback 

     (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7490:22)
     09-11 17:11:07.561: I/chromium(30165): [INFO:CONSOLE(1038)] "processMessage failed: Stack: 
      ReferenceError: google is not defined
     09-11 17:11:07.561: I/chromium(30165):     at wlCommonInit 
    (file:///android_asset/www/default/js/main.js:45:8)
     09-11 17:11:07.561: I/chromium(30165):     at wlEnvInit 
     (file:///android_asset/www/default/js/main.js:53:5)
     09-11 17:11:07.561: I/chromium(30165):     at Object.wlInit [as onSuccess] 

     (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7394:5)
     09-11 17:11:07.561: I/chromium(30165):     at finalizeInit 
     (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:6744:15)
    09-11 17:11:07.561: I/chromium(30165):     at Object.<anonymous> 
     (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7564:7)
    09-11 17:11:07.561: I/chromium(30165):     at Object.<anonymous> 
     (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1202:33)
    09-11 17:11:07.561: I/chromium(30165):     at fire 
     (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1047:30)
    09-11 17:11:07.561: I/chromium(30165):     at Object.self.fireWith [as resolveWith] 
   (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1158:7)
    09-11 17:11:07.561: I/chromium(30165):     at Object.deferred.(anonymous function) [as 
    resolve](file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:1247:34)
    09-11 17:11:07.561: I/chromium(30165):     at deviceIDSuccessCallback 
     (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/worklight.js:7490:22)", source: 
    file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/cordova.js (1038)
    09-11 17:11:07.561: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(30165): Unable to open asset URL:     
    file:///android_asset/www/default/images/favicon.png
    09-11 17:11:07.571: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:07.571: E/qdmemalloc(30165): 
    09-11 17:11:07.571: E/qdmemalloc(30165): heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
    09-11 17:11:07.571: E/qdmemalloc(30165):
```

Comment: Navigate in Eclipse to the generated Android project\assets\www\default folder, do you see all of your resources (files) and content (contents of index.html)?

Comment: Also, what do you see in LogCat when running the app in the device?

Comment: Yes I can see all the contents and resources in project\assets\www\default folder.

Comment: The error from the log is pretty obvious... uncaught reference error. provide a test application showing the problem so that it could debugged.

Comment: And what is the Worklight version?

Comment: Worklight version is 6.2. The following is my test application.        https://db.tt/npfKTT8q

Comment: The application is not available for download, please provide it again.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used the store locator that is provided by Google  as-is, well, with 1 change only: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-store-locator/blob/gh-pages/examples/gme.js

Steps:

1. Created a new project and application, add the Android environment
2. Edited index.html by adding two DIVs to the `body` element:

   ```
   <div id="panel"></div>
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
   ```
3. Edited main.js by copy-pasting the contents of gme.js into the wlCommonInit() function
4. Removed the following since it is not needed because we are inside wlCommonInit which gets auto-called once the Worklight-based app is ready:

   ```
   `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {`
   ```

   You will also need to remove its corresponding `});` down below.
5. Built and deployed, ran in the Android Emulator and successfully displayed store locations.